# NSFetchRequest returns wrong value of .count

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, widgetkit

In my app which uses SwiftUI for interface I have a button that performs an action:

```
func getBooksCountNumber() -> Int {
    var countResult = 0
    let booksFetch = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Book")
    
    do {
        let booksFetch = try self.persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(booksFetch) as! [Book]
        countResult = booksFetch.count
        print("countResult is \(countResult)")
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to fetch: \(error)")
    }

    return countResult
}
```

When I delete rows in the app I use `moc.delete(book)` and `try? moc.save()`. I see that deleted rows gone, using interface at icloud.developer.apple.com. For example — if from 3 records I delete 1, I still getting 3 in `countResult` and not 2. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated but there is a [count(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506868-count) API and specify the generic type in the fetch request `NSFetchRequest<Book>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SwiftUI relies on data invalidation to force a `View` to reload.

So you need to think about how you make your `View` code rely on the change in your data, for `countResult` (as an example).

If you're using SwiftUI, I'd recommend that you consider using the `@FetchRequest` property wrapper to acquire your dataset...

```
@FetchRequest(entity: Book.entity(),
              sortDescriptors: []
) var books: FetchedResults<Book>
```

Note: the `sortDescriptors:` parameter is required, so if you do not want to sort the `FetchedResults`, you include an empty array `[]`.

Then use the property associated with that wrapper to feed the data into your view...

```
struct YourView: View {
    // @FetchRequest here
    var body: some View {
        ...
        Text("Book count = \(books.count)")
        ...
    }
}
```

This way, you don't even need to press the button to determine the count, because the `Text` view is updated each time a book is added to or deleted from your `Book` entity.

Written in a SwiftUI way, as the data changes, the `Text` view component will be invalidated and the view `struct` will be forced to redraw.

If you want to keep the button in your view, you could do something like this instead...

```
    var body: some View {
        ...
        Button(action: {
            // code to perform your action here...
        }) {
            Text("You have \(books.count) books")
        }
        ...
    }
```

Where the label of the button includes the count of books (and the button performs some other action).